# problema al comparar por formato de fecha

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

Recupero una fecha de un registro que esta en la BD y me trae en este formato "07/01/2016 05:43:10 p.m.", después comparo esa fecha para hacer una condición para que actualice mi registro ya que es el único campo que puede ser diferente para todos los demás registros de mi BD, no  puedo modificar el diseño de la tabla, solo puedo hacer uso de los registros, ese formato de fecha me esta trayendo problemas ya que el formato de la fecha de mi BD es "2016-01-07 17:43:11.790", por lo que eh probado mi update desde SQL Server y el "p.m." es el problema por el cual no esta actualizando, como podría quitar el "p.m.", ya use

```html
Dim fechaCompara = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Form("txtFechaa"))
```

y sigue trayendo "07/01/2016 05:43:10 p.m.", uso VB.NET

Comment: Fijate en la configuración regional de Windows (maquina cliente) y cambia el formato de horas a 24hs (H en mayúscula) y proba de nuevo

Comment: se puede hacer de forma mas general, es decir desde codigo ya que es una aplicación web y pues es mas conveniente formatear la fecha desde la pagina @ArielOctavioD'Alfeo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema puede estar en la configuración regional, pero una solución algo genérica es esta:

```
Dim fechaCompara As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Parse(Request.Form("txtFechaa")).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"))
```

O bien, de la misma forma que lo has hecho tú:

```
Dim fechaCompara = DateTime.Parse(Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Form("txtFechaa")).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"))
```

Donde `.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss")` convierte a string la cadena de fecha que obtienes al principio (`07/01/2016 05:43:10 p.m.`) en `07-01-2016 17:43:10`

Para luego convertir `07-01-2016 17:43:10` en `DateTime`

Al llamarlo, tedras un objeto de tipo `DateTime`, con la configuración regional que necesitas.

Answer (score 1):

El formato que tengas en la db no afecta en nada, pero si deberias enviar un datetime como parametro de la query que ejecutes

```
Dim fechaCompara As DateTime= Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Form("txtFechaa"))

Using conn As New SqlConnection("<connection string>")
    conn.Open()

    Dim query As String = "UPDATE NombreTabla SET fecha = @fecha WHERE campo = @id"
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(query, conn)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha", fechaCompara)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(txtId.Text))

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

No importa el formato de la fecha siempre que uses parametro y asignes un datetime valido